# Does it make sense to use dropout in last layer of regression neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, lstm, keras, dropout

I have a neural network that I constructed in `keras` that goes from a LSTM recurrent layer > dropout > flattened > dense layer of 1 unit.

**Does this make sense to have dropout regularization at this stage?**  Would this be creating sparsity in the penultimate layer or would it be evening out the connections to the final prediction?

```
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 60, 512)           1181696   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 512)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 30720)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 30721     
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. Check out [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3061/db5aab0b3f6070ea0f19f8e76470e44aefa5.pdf) paper.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is wrong. The paper you linked is for a classification task.